# Unit tests fail after upgrading from NServiceBus 7 to NServiceBus 8

Tags: c#, testing, nservicebus

After upgrading my application to use NServiceBus 8 from NServiceBus 7 I had problems with my unit test project.  I upgraded the NServiceBus.Testing package that my unit test project depends on to version 8.1.0, and my unit tests now fail with the following message:

System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'NServiceBus.IMessageProcessingContextExtensions' from assembly 'NServiceBus.Core, Version=8.0.0.0, ...'

My unit tests use the TestableMessageHandlerContext() and I'm passing that into my .Handle() on my handler object.  That's when the error is thrown; when the .Handle() is invoked.

Referring to Particular's documentation one is supposed to use TestableMessageHandlerContext() with NserviceBus 8 (https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/testing-7to8)  so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Turned out there were some projects in my solution that were missing the upgrade.    It happens.  Lesson is always recheck the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out there were some projects in my solution that were missing the upgrade.    It happens.  Lesson is always recheck the basics.